# Nativescript Vue Release Build App not installing

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to build a relase version of a nativescript vue app. I have followed the following instrucitons: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps
When I put the resulting apk on my phone it trys to install the app and after a few seconds tells me that `app was not installed`. A debug apk is working fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: am having the same problem, did you get a solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must completely uninstall your debug APK from your device before you can install the release version. If you go to Settings -> Applications (menu may vary depending on your device vendor & android version), you will find your application and you have use the option named uninstall for all users. Then you must be able to install your release version. This is a common problem when you use APKs with different keystore (debug vs release) on same device.

You may also uninstall the app using ADB command.

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

Comment: Thanks solved it. That piece of information should really be included in the official documentation. For other people using nativescript Vue don't forget to include `--bundle` during build process.

Answer (score 0):

Change the minimuSdk to 17
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__" />
```

app\Android_Resources\Android\app.gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 17
  }
```